# Objective C, Mac X coredata

Tags: objective-c, macos, core-data

I want to create a Mac OS X app that uses a database "backend" in a local dir.

I can make a project with a UI that has a table view and that uses a data model/array controller. I can add "records" and remove them etc. Everything works great until I want to close the application. When I try and close the program it wants to know where I want to save the document.

The problem is that I want the program to use only one "document".

Is this possible? If so how? Do you have a link to a tutorial for a Mac OS X app?

Comment: what is up with the down vote? wtf?

Answer (score 0):

Simply turn the document support off (Create Document-based Application), when you create the project.

Changing that after the project is created is possible, but needs more work than creating a new project and copying the files into that.

Comment: if i do and set up my table view/array controller in the same way i get errors - such as "Cannot perform operation without a managed object context"

Comment: Thank you!! finally got it - i had to do like you said and turn off the .. "document based app" then i had to change the array controller's bindings and set the model key path to managedObjectContext - and a couple of other things... anyway thanks for the help Amin!!